# Too Many Characters Included in Attempt to Parse a CSV File

Tags: regex, csv, pcre, capture-group

### Background

I am attempting to parse a CSV file using PCRE regular expressions. That is, making out (or extracting) the various different "cells" available in the CSV, to then put them in a somewhat nicely organized array containing all the parts that the process of parsing managed to make out.

The following regular expression is what I have come up with so far:

```
/(?:;|^)(?:(?:"(?:(?!"(;|$)).)*)|(?:([^;]*)))/g
```

I would highly recommend that you put this in a tester for regular expressions. Here is a slight bit of test data, that should match to a great extent.

> `"There; \"be";"but; someone spoke";hence the young man;hence the son;"test;"`

### The Problem

The regular expression manages to extract the correct number of parts. It is meant for the regular expression to retrieve the text from inside each and every "cell" available in the CSV (use the CSV provided above for reference). It does to some extent.

Here is the result of the groups in the regular expression above:

> `"There; \"be`
>   `;"but; someone spoke`
>   `hence the young man`
>   `hence the son`
>   `;"test;`

As we can clearly see, the lines that are "escaped" using double-quotation marks include the `"` inside its group for the match, also selects the `"`, and sometimes even the semi-colon. From my understanding, the group for the negative lookahead should not include those.

I have probably missed something very essential here. Perhaps someone can point me in the right direction towards a fix.

### Edit and Potential Solution

It appears as though I might have managed to solve it. As opposed to what I said above, the negative lookahead does not actually appear to create a capture group, which I initially thought. As such, adding yet another group to the equation seems to parse out the segments I am after.

```
/(?:;|^)(?:(?:"((?:(?!"(;|$)).)*))|(?:([^;]*)))/g
```

I will, however, leave the question open for now, and will answer it myself if no other answer comes tumbling in. As not to make it opinion based, I would therefore further inquire as to whether there might be a more efficient way in terms of speed than that in which I am using above.

Comment: Is there a reason this has to be done with regular expressions?

Comment: @Oliver I was thinking it might be the quickest way to parse it, and speed is essential. The parsing itself is done for a locales module for a PHP framework. Nevertheless, I am extremely interested in the reason as to why the behavior described above is taking place!

Comment: I googled "php parse csv", and [this is the first result](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php). Don't try to use some crazy regex for this, just use the standard library.

Comment: Your solution doesn't even work properly, will have little-to-no performance gain (it may even be worse!), and will confuse the hell out of other developers.

Comment: Try parsing this: `"Column \"; One";"Column Two"` -- Your regex is flawed.

Comment: @D.Ataro as other have pointed out, regular expressions will not perform as well as other parsing methods.  It would be worth looking into existing libraries that you can use for this.  Alternatively there will be good code examples of csv parsing out there that don't use regex.

Comment: @Oliver The problem I am faced with is the fact that I need to parse the lines individually. In the locales module I am currently in the process of creating, there might be hundreds of locales available. Existing libraries and "methods" would parse the whole thing, when a totality of two lines at the very most is what needs be parsed.

Comment: @TomLord Yes, you are very right. That is a problem that might (and probably will) occur. I shall extend my question to inquire about this problem, as it is very closely related to the initial question.

Comment: @TomLord Actually. I did some further testing. The regular expression I provided near the end of my question works just fine. The example you attached would, to my current understanding of CSV files, never occur, should the CSV file be created and saved with for instance Microsoft Excel.

Comment: @D.Ataro Of course it could. Just enter `Column "; One` in a cell. The problem is that your solution assumes "any quotation mark followed by a semi-colon represents the end of the column", which is not necessarily true, as shown above.

Comment: @TomLord You are very correct! It appears as though I will need to do a little bit more work regarding that regular expression of mine. Meanwhile, there is still a question to be answered. Let us put our minds together! From my understanding, however, the code you provided would look like `"Column \"; One"`, as there is a semi-colon in there. At the very least, this is what Microsoft Excel should "compile" it to.

Comment: *"I will need to do a little bit more work regarding that regular expression of mine"* -- Or, like I said originally, just use the standard library to parse the CSV? I could write you a regex to solve this properly, but it's the wrong approach to use.

Comment: Essentially, you'd need to match either (1) A non-quotation mark, up to the first semi-colon/end of line, or (2) A quotation mark, up to the next quotation mark that's not proceeded by an odd number of backslashes.